# Where to download numeric extension of Generic Image Library of BOOST

Tags: c++, image-processing, boost

[Generic image library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html) is a very interesting library for image processing, and it has been part of BOOST library for a long time. Based on this library, new image processing algorithms can be easily incorporated. The authors of the library also give some extension examples such as [this one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/gil/example/affine.cpp). In this example the numerical extension files are needed, which will not be downloaded with the library. I tried to find these extension files but failed. Does anyone know where I can find them. Thanks.

Comment: All the documentation that describes where to find GIL extensions is from 2007. I was also looking for the "numeric" GIL extension and had tried many other avenues. This question, and the answer below, was the only breadcrumb that was actually helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find them here: http://gil-contributions.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
(Its extremely hard to find!)

Comment: The link is dead @ 2016/6/1.

Comment: link does not work anymore - any chance you know another place to find it - it seems even boost.org have some links :

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/boost/gil/extension/numeric/sampler.hpp
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/boost/gil/extension/numeric/resample.hpp

Comment: Yes, the link died since I posted it 3 years ago! Boost has the extension now (see links in above comment by @serup